# Is Louise Belcher ever depicted without her hat?

Tags: bobs-burgers

I watch Bob's Burgers pretty often, but I've never seen Louise without her distinctive pink bunny-ears hat. Even during episodes where the hat itself is not worn Louise's character maintains some kind of period-appropriate bunny-ears-themed headwear.

Has she ever been depicted without her iconic headpiece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, in the episode '*Ear-sy Rider*'** (S03E01).

Tina, Gene, and Louise run into some "*little acne-covered kittens*" "*who took over the steps*".
Fearless as always, Louise doesn't want to walk around the playground, and during their second confrontation, Logan, one of these high-school kids, "confiscates" the bunny ears:

[image]

The camera tilts up before we can take a glance at the uncowled Louise, and for a big chunk of the episode she wears a dark blue hoodie:

[image]

Ultimately, she uses the One-Eyed Snakes biker gang to press Logan into giving the ears back, and their reunion is glorious.

---

If your intention was to get an idea of Louise's haircut, however: we can see a resemblance with that of her mother's haircut, although her tails are tied together with yellow ribbons:

[image]